# Delete item from nested array in Schema using moongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I need help with removing `this` item from nested array. I tried used `$http.delete` but this method deleted whole ObjectID from database, and second problem is that I can't connect the click on the "removing" button with backend code.

My code:

```
var product = new Schema({
  title: String,
  price: String,
  description: [ObjectID]
});
```

Index.html

```
<form name="editProduct.descriptionForm" ng-submit="editProduct.updateDescription(newDescription, editProduct.descriptionForm.description.$valid)" novalidate>
  <div ng-class="{ 'has-success':(editProduct.descriptionForm.description.$valid && !editProduct.descriptionForm.description.$pristine), 'has-error':(!editProduct.descriptionForm.description.$valid && !editProduct.descriptionForm.description.$pristine) || (!descriptionForm.description.$valid && descriptionForm.$submitted) }">

    <div class="entry input-group" ng-repeat="item in newDescription track by $index">
      <strong><input ng-disabled="editProduct.disabled" class="form-control" type="text" name="description" ng-model="newDescription[$index]" required></strong>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a ng-click="editProduct.deleteDescription(item);" class="btn btn-remove btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button ng-disabled="editProduct.disabled" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

routes.js

```
router.put('/editProduct', function(req, res){
  var editProduct = req.body._id;
  var options = { multi: true };
  Product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: editProduct }, { $pull: { description: req.params.description }}, options, function(err, product){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!product){
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Product no found' });
    } else {
      product.update(function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.json({ success: true, message: 'Description removed!'})
        }
      });
    };
  });   
});
```

I also tried the following approach:

```
Product.findOne({'_id' : product.id}, function(err, me){
  for(var i=0; i<=me.description.length; i++){
    if (String(me.description[i])==String(uid)){
      me.description.remove(uid);
      me.save();                         
    }
  }    
});
```

I think, the biggest problem is that I don't how to connect this function to the button.

Comment: I would split your problem into 2-3 small ones.

Comment: It looks terrible, but I think that problem is short, maybe someone be up against removing item from array click on <button> or <a>

Answer (score 1):

Please try `console.log(req.params.description)` Before the Mongoose update query and check if the output is indeed a valid ObjectId.

If the console output is not showing the valid uid, then the problem is in the angular code. Most probably in `editProduct.deleteDescription(item)` function. Check if you are making Http Request by passing the correct Description Id as the parameter. Thats probably something like item.descriptionId or item.id. Debug thoroughly.

Comment: Everything seems works good, but I got message "Product no found"